# sybase ase 15.0.3 licence for developer edition

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I did fresh install for sybase ase 15.0.3 EBF21291 on linux. In setup i chose Developer edition. After server startup i noticed that in log files there is this message

```
SySAM: Checked out graced license for 1 ASE_CORE (2013.0704) will expire Sat Apr 12 18:13:30 2014.
SySAM: License file does not support this version. ASE requires a license version of 2013.0704 or greater but only licenses for previous releases are available. If you are entitled to use this version of ASE then check for updates at the Sybase Product Download Center and regenerate and deploy your license updates.
SySAM: License feature name:  ASE_CORE
SySAM: Application version > License version: 2013.0704 > 2011.1231
SySAM: License search path:   /opt/sybase/ase1503/SYSAM-2_0/licenses/SYBASE_ASE_DE.lic:
SySAM: FLEXnet Licensing error:-21,126
SySAM: For further information, refer to the Sybase Software Asset Management website at http://www.sybase.com/sysam
Error: 131274, Severity: 17, State: 1
```

Licence file is for Developer edition.
also   sp_lmconfig gives

```
Parameter Name    Config Value
edition           DE
license type      DT
----
ASE_CORE                   1        graced       Apr 12 2014  6:13PM
```

Googling where not fruitful to me. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried stopping and starting the license manager, and the Database?  It could be that the license didn't get picked up for some reason, maybe?

Comment: This is a question that should be directed to Sybase Tech Support.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a question that should go to the vendor Technical Support staff.

Comment: I did restart server. License file is in correct path, i haven't touched it after install. Inside i can see that it says it belongs to DE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Developer edition licenses for older releases expired as shown in log at 
`License version: 2013.0704 > 2011.1231`
to get working license you need newer version for example ASE 15.7 installed in Developer editions and get license at `SYSAM-2_0/licenses` copied into older editions licenses folder.